# How can i limit number of tags that could be related to item?

Tags: django, tagging

I need to limit number of tags than can be related to item. It always should be max 5 tags.

```
        tags = form.cleaned_data['tags']
        item.tags = tags
        item.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good idea to do this in clean method of form

```
class MyForm(forms.Form)
    ...

    def clean_tags(self):
       tags=  self.cleaned_data['tags']
       if len(tags.split(" ")) > 5:
          raise forms.ValidationError("you can only add 5 tags")
       return tags
```

**EDIT**
This will be checked when you will call form.is_valid(). When error occurs it is added to form.tags.errors

**EDIT**

so just

```
return tags.split(" ")[:5]
```

Comment: yes, but it only check for tags number. I need something that will take first 5 tags no matter how many will be try to add

Comment: strange things comes like `[u'pi\u0119\u015b\u0107'  u'si\u0119'  u'smoka'  u'w']  u'wrzyna'`

Comment: try to pass unicode string as tags. maybe there is a problem with coding. if your tags are not separated by space change argument in split function

Comment: Can you paste here content of tags field?

Comment: `class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True)`

Comment: Please past a string which is in self.cleaned_data['tags'] and add it to question content

Answer (score 1):

Assuming tags is a set or list ?!

```
tags = form.cleaned_data['tags']
if len(tags) < 5:
    item.tags = tags
    item.save()
else:
    print "Oopsy"
```

Humm you want

```
tags = form.cleaned_data['tags']
item.tags = tags[:5]
item.save()
```

Comment: yes, but it only check for tags number. I need something that will take first 5 tags no matter how many will be try to add